# Is Eclipse RAP (web port of RCP) compatible with weblogic?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I'm wondering if anybody succeed or has a proof of successfull deployment of a Eclipse RAP application on Weblogic, whatever the version of RAP and Weblogic he's using.

I get an HTTP 404 (servlet mapping is correct ;) ) while it is working on Jboss and Websphere.

I found track of somebody in trouble with weblogic:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=99215&th=30503

And a collegue of mine with same error:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=657561&th=205488

Any idea/report of success/failure is welcomed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is successfully working. Problem was related to SAXParserFactory.
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=766819&tstart=60&start=15.

Edit:
EJB calls from RAP are not working on Weblogic (ClassCastException). They are working on both Jboss and Websphere.